# Changing ID in Bootstrap 4 Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, bootstrap-4

I am using the bootstrap 4 datatables stuff found at https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4
In there example they set the id for the table to "example":

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-card" style="width:100%">
```

How can I change it so instead of the javascript looking for the id "example" it looks for a class value, like "bootstrap-table"?  I have searched both the js files dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js and jquery.dataTables.min.ns and cannot find where they find the table by using the id value "example.

Comment: Just change the selector , `$('#example').DataTable();` to  `$('.bootstrap-table').DataTable(); ` it should work

Comment: I couldnt find where in the javascript code the selector is

Comment: The selector means `$("#example")` this jQuery statement will select any dom element with id attribute as   `id=example` ,where as `$('.bootstrap-table')` will select any dom element with class as `class=bootstrap-table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can just change the selector like so:

**from** `$('#id').DataTable();` **to** `$('.bootstrap-table').DataTable();`

hope that helps

here is my codepen if you want to try it out https://codepen.io/CodeBoyCode/pen/mzQZNE

Comment: I couldnt find where in the javascript code the selector is

Comment: within the answer above - the from and to's are selectors